# JPAReposiry fetch all the object instead the one I want

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to get just where the channel is true (1)  from sql but when I do the same query on JPARepository it fetch all the rows from the many table
my query on sql is this: :

```
select * FROM tbl_archive A JOIN tbl_channel C ON(C.ARCHIVE_ID =A.ARCHIVE_ID)
WHERE a.identifier='NGLCRS97D12G866L' AND c.ENABLED_CHANNEL=1
```

and I get this result (I wanna this one):

[image]

```
when I try to do this on JPARepository:

    @Query(value = "select * FROM TBL_ARCHIVE A JOIN TBL_CHANNEL C ON(C.ARCHIVE_ID =A.ARCHIVE_ID) " +
            "WHERE a.identifier= :identifier AND c.ENABLED_CHANNEL=1", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Archive> findChannelEnabled(@Param("identifier") String identifier, Pageable pageable);
```

I get this in the json Result:

[image]

but I don't need where is false.
I also tried this queries too but nothing changed, when fetch the result it will fetch all the channels (many) who has a relation with Archive (one)

```
    Page<Archive> findByIdentifierAndChannelsEnabledChannelTrue(String identifier, Pageable pageable);
```

My Models are these:

```
public class Archive {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ARCHIVE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
    private Long archiveId;
    @Column(name = "IDENTIFIER")
    private String identifier;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "archive")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Channel> channels;
}
public class Channel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
    private Long channelId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "archive_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Archive archive;

    @Column(name = "Channel_Name")
    private String channelName;

    @Column(name = "ENABLED_CHANNEL")
    private Boolean enabledChannel;
}
```

My service:

```
public Page<Archive> getChannelEnabled(String identifier) {
        return archiveRepo.findChannelEnabled(identifier, PageRequest.of(0, 10));
    }
```

Comment: You should update your question and attach source of service which returns json response. Perhaps this service executes another repository method - we don't see it

Comment: @Alex I added the service

Comment: try this  :  Page<Archive>  findByIdentifierAndChannelsEnabledChannelTrue(String identifier,Pageable pageable)

Comment: Try `@Query(value = "from Archive a where a.identifier = :identifier and a.channels.enabledChannel = 1")`

Comment: With @hamwac5's suggesstion, remove the `@Query` annotation

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I tried your and I got thisQuery exception:
`illegal attempt to dereference collection [archive0_.archive_id.channels] with element property reference [enabledChannel] [from com.example.NetflixProve.model.Archive a where a.identifier = :identifier and a.channels.enabledChannel = 1]`

Comment: The query gives you exactly what you asked for. Al archives that have a channel that is activated. That is the question you asked. It will fetch the `Archive` including all its relations (as that is what JPA does). If you only want channels then only select those.

Comment: @M.Deinum so with the query I do It gonna fetch all the many side? How may I get just what I want?

Comment: @hamwac5 I have already try yours but It won't work

Comment: The query is selecting `Archive` entities **not** `Channel` entities (directly). As the `Archive` has a list of `Channel` it will eventually retrieve all of those. If you only want `Channel` write a query that selects the `Channel` and no `Archive`.

Comment: @M.Deinum so the only way is to do from the ChannelRepository? Isn't another way to get from there just the row that I fetch, for now I just tried to do a stream.filter to fix but I just wondering on the performance given

Comment: No, I'm going to iterate again, you are selecting `Archive` entities and that will eventually have everything in there according to the mapping. So without either selecting only `Channel` or mapping the result to a dedicated DTO (projection) the result is going to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by modifying your repository method like this:

```
@Query(value = "select a FROM Archive a join fetch a.channels c where a.identifier=:identifier and c.enabledChannel=1",
            countQuery = " select count(a) from Archive a left join a.channels where a.identifier=:identifier")
Page<Archive> findChannelEnabled(@Param("identifier") String identifier, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: It Worked!!!!! thanks a lot, May I ask you about the count operation?

Comment: @Robs it is needed for calculating pages. If you return just `Collection<Archive>` without `Pageable` arg you won't need it at all

Comment: Do you know if I have to do this with a nativeQuery=true what should I do? because in my projects there ara 2 native query that probably I will have to modify

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [NumericBooleanType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/NumericBooleanType.html) which, according to the definition, *maps between `INTEGER` and `Boolean` (using `1` and `0`).*

```
@Column(name = "ENABLED_CHANNEL")
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
private Boolean enabledChannel;
```

Comment: Changing the mapping won't suddenly make the query work.

Comment: The query is a native query, which doesn't even use the type. Nor is the explicit setting needed for the type as hibernate can deduce this based on the type and column-type / database.

Comment: Thank you for the info, didn't pay attention to the native query.